# PostgreSQL - Foreign Key parcial de Primary Key composta

Tags: sql, postgresql, modelagem, chave-estrangeira

Fala galera,

Preciso criar um modelo de estrutura em que todas minhas tabelas tenham chave primária composta por id e versão, de forma que posso ter varias versões para cada id.

Problema:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 {
    id              BIGSERIAL,
    version         INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_table1 PRIMARY KEY (id, version)
}

CREATE TABLE table2 {
    id              BIGSERIAL,
    version         INT NOT NULL,
    table1_id       BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_table2 PRIMARY KEY (id, version),
    CONSTRAINT fk_table1 FOREIGN KEY (table1_id) REFERENCES table1(id)
}
```

Ao executar a estrutura acima, por não referenciar todos os campos da chave primária composta da `table1` na FK, o seguinte erro é retornado:

`ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "table1 "`

Minha duvida esta no relacionamento com outras tabelas. Eu gostaria de não precisar  criar um campo de versão para cada FK que eu criar na tabela para simplificar a quantidade de campos, conseguir manter o relacionamento do registros apenas por id e controlar o histórico do relacionamento por campos de data/hora.

Eu já li a [documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) do Postgre sobre a clausula `MATCH PARTIAL` que acredito que seria minha solução, porém ainda não foi implementada.

- **Existe algum work around para esta situação?**
- **O que estou fazendo vai contra algum principio de modelagem de dados? Devo correr para uma solução diferente?**

Estou utilizando o PostgreSQL versão 10.5.

Comment: FK de PK composta, precisa referencias todos os campos se não me engano. `CONSTRAINT fk_table1 FOREIGN KEY (id, version) REFERENCES (table1)`

Comment: @rbz isso não irá funcionar porque na `table2` apenas tem um campo referente à `table1`. E se ao invés de colocar a coluna `version` como parte da chave primária não cria a chave primária apenas com o `id` e depois uma `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` com os dois?

Comment: @JoãoMartins, se eu deixasse apenas o `id` como PK, ele teria que ser único. Eu gostaria de manter um registro de versão para cada id.

Comment: Então aí não vai conseguir ter o que pretende. A FK precisa sempre de referenciar uma coluna específica e não uma chave composta (que poderiam ser múltiplas colunas).

Comment: Opa: `CONSTRAINT fk_table1 FOREIGN KEY (id, version) REFERENCES table1(id, version)`

Comment: @JoãoMartins imaginei =/. Parece ser um problema de modelagem, então.

Comment: Eu acho que estou entendendo errado, pelo que estou lendo os comentários! rs...

Comment: eu entendo que o ideal é você ter um campo que seja _identity_ (mesmo que não chave primária) para referenciar na `table2`, assim você mantém a relação de 1 pra 1 com a `table1` e a estrutura de chave composta na tabela "principal"

Comment: @rbz hehehe acho que sim. Eu sei como eu referencio chave composta, mas eu queria não precisar informar todos os campos da PK na FK. Mas agradeço o interesse =)

Comment: A ideia do @rLinhares é de boa! Criar um campo _dummy_ apenas para ser chave primária e depois criar uma `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` com o `id` e `version`, assim garantia que a composição das duas colunas era única e já tinha uma chave primária única também que conseguiria referenciar corretamente na `table2`!

Comment: @rLinhares entendi e gostei da ideia. Vou fazer um teste e atualizo a thread

Comment: me parece um problema X,Y... se explicar seu problema real, podemos propor uma solução ideal... ter um registro e na mesma tabela seu versionamento me parece muito estranho

Comment: @RovannLinhalis acho que o que a ideia de uma chave resolve o problema em questão (o que talvez caracterize mesmo um problema XY), mas entendo que o ponto levantado sobre _"como usar parte de uma chave composta"_ seja válido (pelo menos fiquei intrigado sobre a possibilidade =p)

Comment: "como usar parte de uma chave composta" já não faz sentido pra mim, a chave estrangeira iria referenciar mais de um registro na tabela estrangeira... a questão do  MATCH PARTIAL, entendo que diz respeito as chaves estrangeiras (ou parte) poderem ser nulas ou não, vide MATCH FULL e MATCH SIMPLE... ou seja, em nenhum caso a chave poderia fazer referência a mais de um registro na tabela de origem. Sobre o problema em questão, seria melhor o AP definir o que ele quer controlar versões e essas deveriam estar em uma terceira tabela, mas só ele explicando para termos certeza

Comment: @RovannLinhalis entendi, e acho que faz sentido. eu não estava pensando em parte de uma chave composta como sendo chave primária de outra tabela, sendo possível sim que ela se repetisse...

Comment: Se em seu modelo faz sentido utilizar apenas o campo id então crie uma tabela apenas com este campo e outra tabela com este campo + versão e utilize cada uma delas quando for mais adequado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considerando todos os comentários, e em especial a indicação do [@rLinhares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64073/rlinhares), será que isto resolverá o seu problema?

```
CREATE TABLE table1 
{
    dummy_id        BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    id              BIGSERIAL   NOT NULL,
    version         INT         NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(id, version)
}

CREATE TABLE table2
{
    dummy_id        INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    id              BIGSERIAL   NOT NULL,
    version         INT         NOT NULL,
    table1_id       BIGINT      NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT      fk_table1   FOREIGN KEY (table1_id) REFERENCES table1(dummy_id),
    UNIQUE(id, version)
}
```

Comment: thanks my king, very helpful your answer =)